# iOS: Resizing UIImageView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I am new to AutoLayout and struggling with it a bit. I have a `UIImageView` which is part of an UIView. When the app is running on a **3.5 inch** device, I want the UIImageView to resize according to the change of the screen size.

I am not sure how to achieve this. From what I have seen so far, you can only set a fixed width and height of the views, is it possible to make them **dynamically resize** ? In other words, how can the `UIImageView` resize accordingly to the super view's height ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Choose your ImageView in Interface Biulder.
2. Press pin button.
3. Set the constraints.

Example
[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. But rather than giving constant values, what if you give ratio which will adjust the position and the size of the UIImageView. If you think that is a good option, this is the way of how to tackle [iOS AutoLayoout with UIImageView](https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/ios-autolayout-with-a-uiimageview/)

Answer (score 3):

This code will size the `UIImageView` according to its superview's width and height.

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];

[myImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSArray *imageViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myImageView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"myImageView": myImageView}];
[self.view addConstraints:imageViewConstraints];

imageViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myImageView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"myImageView": myImageView}];
[self.view addConstraints:imageViewConstraints];
```

Answer (score 1):

Me too faced same problem.It may help someone,

If you are designing in InterfaceBuilder or Storyboard just pin all the edges to superview (i.e)Leading Space,Trailing Space,Top Space and Bottom Spoace to UIView.
That's it

Answer (score -2):

select the imageView. Now go and add a pin with bottom spacing from super view.

Comment: This only creates a bottom spacing, the image size is left unchanged.